# CSV:Powershell: Deleting rows containing specific word in the cell

Tags: csv, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am having trouble in parsing the csv and deleting the rows as per the requirement.

1. My csv file format is not even, and there are many columns which are blank, But I want them to be considered as proper cells
2. csv has some rows (not fixed number of rows) before the actual header and at the bottom there may be a chance of having 2 lines. I want my csv to start from the header instead of the first line.

   > `Import-Csv file.csv | Get-Member`

this code only gives me two member types but csv has more than 20columns

csv example:

1,ab

x,33,455

blank line

x,12,134

some more lines

f,er,fsdvf

blank lines

headers start here, 20+columns

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have there is not CSV. What you have is a bunch of lines with letters and commas and no clear pattern. Until you change that, `Import-Csv` won't be able to help you.

Comment: That is the csv which we get from an application and is not possible to change the format.

Comment: That's not my point. You don't have CSV. *Calling* it CSV does not make it CSV.

Comment: Your issue is not *"How do I make `Import-Csv` understand this mess?"*, your issue is *"How can I pre-process this mess so that it becomes something that `Import-Csv` can possibly understand?"*. That's the question you should be thinking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the header (columns) you can always force `Import-Csv` to have these columns even if the first line of the file suggests otherwise:

```
Import-Csv file.csv -Header One, Two, Three, Four
```

Downside is that you end up with some objects that you probably don't need. 
As alternative, you can find line with your header and use `Get-Content`/`ConvertFrom-Csv` combo:

```
$line = Select-String -Path file.csv -Pattern ^One | 
    ForEach-Object LineNumber
Get-Content -Path file.csv | 
    Select-Object -Skip ($line - 1) | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Regular expression should probably be more verbose, but overall that should be easiest that convincing application producing fake CSVs to the it proper.